# Why is this question, Wired Connection Problem, protected?

Tags: support

I'm not sure I should be asking this, but why is this question, [Wired Connection Problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/130069/25656), protected? While it has had 3451 views, as of now, there's very little there today that points to why it needed to be protected.
I also see that it has been "active" today but don't see any activity dated today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question was protected automatically by [Community user](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) because three "answers" were flagged as non-answers and subsequently deleted by one of the  community moderators.

- [Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)

Regarding no visible activity today, [Community user](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) [randomly pokes old, unanswered questions so they get some attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/177471). As the Community user bumps it, it gets pushed to the top of the front page. Very clearly, someone then upvoted the answer in this question. See the [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/130069/timeline) of the entire post.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing forensic facilities available :)

Comment: It looks like *timeline* is not generally available :-)